# How convert protobuf-net object to xml?

Tags: serialization, protobuf-net

How convert protobuf-net object to xml? I have very big object which is contained in protobuf-net format file. I want visualize all fields and sub-fields of this object in xml format. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Since protobuf-net aims to target idiomatic .net types, most types that work well with protobuf-net will also work fine with `XmlSerializer` (and other serializers such as json.net, JIL). So basically: just try `XmlSerializer`:

```
YourRootObject obj = ...
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(YourRootObject));
ser.Serialize(destination, obj);
```

Comment: Marc, does protobuf-net support XML serialization?